# dplyr: Count number of matches of column A with several other columns and write to new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table like this:

```
ID  |   Word1   | Word2     | Word3     | Word4 | Word5 | Word6 | Word7
1   |   like    | grilled   | cheese    | except| omelet| and   | cheese
1   |   like    | grilled   | cheese    | except| omelet| and   | cheese
1   |   like    | grilled   | cheese    | except| omelet| and   | cheese
1   |   like    | grilled   | cheese    | except| omelet| and   | cheese
2   |   i       | have      | to        | write | it    | six   | times
2   |   i       | have      | to        | write | it    | six   | times
```

I would like to add a new column that counts the number of times each word that is in column `Word7` appears in all other `WordX` columns. So for the rows with ID = 1, this new column would have a value of 1 (because cheese occurs in column `Word3`). For rows with ID = 2, it would have a value of 0. But there may also be rows with values of more than 1 if the word in `Word7 occurs in columns 1-6 multiple times.

I've tried a few approached with dplyr `intersect()` and `select()`, but I'm having trouble to even conceptualize this approach (I'm a bit of a noob).

FYI rows with the exact same content in these columns can occur multiple times, but there are other columns with unique values (which however are not relevant for this question, which is why I left them out).

Comment: Here is a way `rowSums(df[,-c(1,8)]==df$Word7)`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what that actually does?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(A=rowSums(.[2:7]==Word7))
```

Using BaseR

```
rowSums(df[,-c(1,8)]==df$Word7)
[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

`df[,-c(1,8)]==df$Word7` will return TRUE and FALSE data frame then we can sum the TRUE's over "in" rows using `RowSums`

## data

```
 df <- read.table(text="
  ID      Word1     Word2       Word3       Word4   Word5   Word6   Word7
                   1       like      grilled     cheese      except  omelet  and     cheese
                   1       like      grilled     cheese      except  omelet  and     cheese
                   1       like      grilled     cheese      except  omelet  and     cheese
                   1       like      grilled     cheese      except  omelet  and     cheese
                   2       i         have        to          write   it      six     times
                   2       i         have        to          write   it      six     times",
       header=T,stringsAsFactor=F)
```

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: Interesting... I get `rowSums(df[, - c(1, 8)] == df$Word7)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0`. That was my first attempt as well but the wrong output pushed me to do `mapply`

Comment: Does `.[2:7]` mean that it just looks at the columns 2 through 7 within the dataframe?

Comment: @rayne yes, if your columns separated then you can try `.[c(2,3,4:7)]==Word7`

Comment: Hmm, I get this message: 
`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: comparison of these types is not implemented.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rowSums(.[1:14, 16:22] == Word22) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "=="
2: In .[1:14, 16:22] == Word22 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: One "all" of your columns is a factor class change it to a character class, you know how to do that ???

Comment: Oh yeah sure, I changed them and now I get this error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column 'A' must be length 33381 (the number of rows) or one, not 14`

Comment: Your data frame is grouped by ID, ungrouped like `df %>% ungroup()%>%mutate(A=`

Comment: When I ungroup, I get the same error as when I have factors :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179484/discussion-between-a-suliman-and-rayne).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do with `mapply`

```
rowSums(mapply(function(x, y) grepl(y, x), df[,-c(1, 8)], df[[8]]))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

You need to use `mapply` which applies a function with x and y arguments one by one (for each line). The function we apply here is to detect the word of `word7` in all other columns (except the ID col which is excluded).Once we do that, we end up with a dataframe with logical statements, of which we do the `rowSums` to count the total number of TRUEs